# Web Application Cache Error Event

Tags: web-applications, iis-7.5, woff

I have an HTML5 web app, with an application cache. I get through 28 of the explicit cache items, and fail on this one (log from Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m)

```
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (404) http://localhost/Toby/Kendo/styles/images/KendoUI.woff
```

Firefox is also not caching (I assume because of this error, but FireBug is not as informative).

I have verified that the WOFF file is present. If I comment this line out of the manifest, then it fails on an svg file:

```
 http://localhost/Toby/Leaflet.Locate/images/locate.svg
```

I am running IIS 7.5 on a win7 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

IIS does not have mime types for:

```
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
AddType text/cache-manifest appcache
AddType image/svg+xml svg
```

I went into the IIS console and added these in as equivelents.

BTW, what should I be setting the appcache (offline.appcache) Output Chaching values to? Rigt now there are none. (user mode? Kernel mode?

Right now, I see that cache and kernel cache is enabled.